# SQL merge overlapping time intervals

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite dataset like this

```
Startdate  | Enddate    | ID 
2019-04-29 | 2019-05-04 | 12
2019-04-23 | 2019-04-25 | 533
2019-04-23 | 2019-04-24 | 44
2019-04-24 | 2019-04-25 | 79
```

I'm trying to get an output that is sorted in range from startdate to startdate plus day in a loop until last Endate.
The plan is to get all observation from min(Startdate) to min(Startdate) +1 and min(Startdate) plus +2 and so one

```
Range                 | ID
2019-04-23 2019-04-24 | 44
2019-04-23 2019-04-25 | 44
2019-04-23 2019-04-25 | 533
2019-04-23 2019-04-25 | 79
2019-04-23 2019-05-04 | 44
2019-04-23 2019-05-04 | 533
2019-04-23 2019-05-04 | 79
2019-04-23 2019-05-04 | 12
```

I'm not sure have to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following will provide the results that you want :-

```
WITH cte(sdate,edate) AS 
    (
        SELECT (SELECT min(startdate) FROM mytable),(SELECT min(startdate) FROM mytable)
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT sdate,date(edate,'+1 days') 
            FROM cte 
            WHERE edate <= (
                SELECT max(enddate) FROM mytable
            ) 
            LIMIT 1000 /* just in case limit to 1000 rows */
    )
SELECT sdate||' '||edate AS Range, id 
FROM cte 
    JOIN mytable ON startdate >= sdate 
        AND enddate <= edate 
        AND edate IN (SELECT enddate FROM mytable)
```

## Example/Test/Demo

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (startdate TEXT, enddate TEXT, id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
    ('2019-04-29','2019-05-04',12),
    ('2019-04-23','2019-04-25',533),
    ('2019-04-23','2019-04-24',44),
    ('2019-04-24','2019-04-25',79)
;
WITH cte(sdate,edate) AS 
    (
        SELECT (SELECT min(startdate) FROM mytable),(SELECT min(startdate) FROM mytable)
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT sdate,date(edate,'+1 days') 
            FROM cte 
            WHERE edate <= (
                SELECT max(enddate) FROM mytable
            ) 
            LIMIT 1000 /* just in case limit to 1000 rows */
    )
SELECT sdate||' '||edate AS Range, id 
FROM cte 
    JOIN mytable ON startdate >= sdate 
        AND enddate <= edate 
        AND edate IN (SELECT enddate FROM mytable)
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
```

The result is :-

[image]

- The only difference being the order of the ID column *(I can't see any order from your expected result)*
- As per the comment LIMIT 1000 is not required